# jQuery event for Radio Input change not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried a few different approaches, none of which seem to work.

Here's my input items HTML:

```
<li><input class="main-page-radio" type="radio" name="mainpage" value="22" checked/> <b>Home</b></li>
<li><input class="main-page-radio" type="radio" name="mainpage" value="11" /> <b>About</b></li>
<li><input class="main-page-radio" type="radio" name="mainpage" value="12" /> <b>Rentals</b></li>
<li><input class="main-page-radio" type="radio" name="mainpage" value="13" /> <b>Contact</b></li>
<li><input class="main-page-radio" type="radio" name="mainpage" value="5" /> <b>Apply</b></li>
```

I have tried both of the following methods in jQuery to get the events to fire, but neither generates the alert:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=mainpage]').change(function(){
        alert('test'); 
    });
});

$(document).on('change', 'input[name="mainpage"]', function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

I've tried using the input ***name*** and ***class***, both with no success. There are no JS errors reported in the console.

Comment: i tried in jsfiddle it's working http://jsfiddle.net/9ru30bat/

Comment: Are you sure you're having jQuery included in your project; or at least this web page?

Comment: Who forgot to include jQuery? :)

Comment: Specific to any browser this issue ?

Comment: jQuery is definitely included. I have about 30 other events using jQuery that are working fine.

Comment: Also, please please please remove this quintuple-inline CSS. My eyes hurt

Comment: The inline CSS is generated by PHP. I will make it a class once I've got the styling correct. Please stick to the issue of the post.

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if it has anything to do with the radio buttons being inside of a Twitter Bootstrap modal. Other events on <button>s work fine though. Doesn't make sense that some elements would work and others wouldn't.

Comment: Figured out the issue. One of the JS files from another plugin was changing how radio events were handled.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working code..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('input:radio[name=mainpage]').change(function() {alert("test")    });
});
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4gZAT/351/) , but it seems no error in your code too. 
Make sure you include "jquery.js"

Comment: Thanks. This looks pretty much identical to my existing code. I have run a few Fiddles and setup a sandbox. All seem to work so it has to be something with my specific page. It's just odd that it doesn't work, yet there are no errors reported.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<ul>
<li style="list-style:none; display:inline-block; margin-right:40px;"><input class="main-page-radio" type="radio" name="mainpage" value="22" checked/> <b>Home</b></li>
<li style="list-style:none; display:inline-block; margin-right:40px;"><input class="main-page-radio" type="radio" name="mainpage" value="11" /> <b>About</b></li>
<li style="list-style:none; display:inline-block; margin-right:40px;"><input class="main-page-radio" type="radio" name="mainpage" value="12" /> <b>Rentals</b></li>
<li style="list-style:none; display:inline-block; margin-right:40px;"><input class="main-page-radio" type="radio" name="mainpage" value="13" /> <b>Contact</b></li>
<li style="list-style:none; display:inline-block; margin-right:40px;"><input class="main-page-radio" type="radio" name="mainpage" value="5" /> <b>Apply</b></li>
    </ul>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=mainpage]').change(function(){
        alert('test'); 
    });
});
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dmvur284/)

Comment: Always a good idea to explain exactly what you've done - instead of expecting people to read through and find the change(s).  I, for one, am struggling to see what you've done differently

Comment: Thanks. This looks pretty much identical to my existing code. I have run a few Fiddles and setup a sandbox. All seem to work so it has to be something with my specific page. It's just odd that it doesn't work, yet there are no errors reported.

Comment: Just add <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> jquery plugin link

Comment: I'm using jQuery already. It's on the page. I have several other jQuery events that work without issue. This is the only one I've had trouble with during this whole project.

Comment: What is your jquery plugin version?

Comment: 2.1.2 I think. Im not at home anymore so I can't check. It's definitely 2+. I did try 1.10 as you suggested and that didn't have any affect. I will do more tests when I get to the office.